# Puppeteer - Having Trouble Selecting Tab That's Internal to a page

Tags: javascript, dom, css-selectors, puppeteer

I have a page with 3 tabs. Global Company Wide and Personal. When I first come to the page, Global is selected by default. I want puppeteer to select Company Wide. This should not involve a change in url. I can't get it to switch tabs. I do get to take the screenshot in the code but it shows the Global tab is still selected.  When I put my selector into dev tools it indicated it was an array so I tried referencing the 0 index but that didn't work either.

Here is a screenshot of the page.
[image]

```js
await page.waitForSelector('a[id="libraryDropdown"]');
//await page.waitForSelector('a[id="libraryDropdown"]>img');

await page.click('a[id="libraryDropdown"]>img');


// THIS NEXT CLICK TRANSITIONS TO COMPANY WIDE LIBRARY
await page.waitForSelector('#lineTab > li:nth-child(2)> a[aria-selected="false"]');

//await page.click('#lineTab > li:nth-child(2)> a[aria-selected="false"]' [0]);
await page.click('#lineTab > li:nth-child(2)> a[aria-selected="false"]');
await page.waitFor(1000);

await page.screenshot({
  path: './__test__/line66.png',
  fullPage: true
});
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs mb-2" id="lineTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link show" id="underline-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#underline-home" role="tab" aria-controls="underline-home" aria-selected="false">Global (Public)</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link show active" id="underline-company-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#underline-      company" role="tab" aria-controls="underline-company" aria-selected="true">Company Wide</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link show" id="underline-personal-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#underline-personal" role="tab" aria-controls="underline-personal" aria-selected="true">Personal</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, `aria-selected` attribute of `a` in the second `li` is `true`, while in the selector it is `false`.

Comment: Good point. Thanks for looking at it. Yes. When I select it the first time it is false because the Global tab is selected. After it is clicked it should be selected, hence true. Does that make sense. The HTML in dev tool changes from true to false, depending on which tab is selected.

Comment: $('#lineTab > li:nth-child(2)> a[aria-selected="false"]')[0].click()  This selector works in dev tools. It causes the tab to switch from Global to company wide. So I changed my code to: await page.click('#lineTab > li:nth-child(2)> a[aria-selected="false"]')[0]; Still not causing the tab to switch but at least I think the selector is corret now. one step forward

Comment: It would be easier for somebody to help if you could provide the URL of the page.

Comment: The issue is it requires login

Comment: when I look at my screenshot taken at line 66, I realized that the page is not fully rendered. The link is not present in the screenshot. I thought it should be because I did 'waitForSelector' I have more current code but there doesn't seem to be a way to post it.

Answer (score 0):

This should perform the trick:

```js
await page.$eval('desired-tab-selector', (el) => el.click());
```

link to the Puppeteer API [Page.$eval()](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page._eval)

> This method runs document.querySelector within the page and passes the
> result as the first argument to the pageFunction *(defined as 2nd arg)*.